# How do i update webview from settings preferences

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

very simple question.  I have an app with a single view (webview) that loads a url.  The app has a settings bundle attached to it with one field asking for a string. Here is the code in my viewcontroller:

-(void)viewDidLoad{

```
[super viewDidLoad];

   NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   NSString *settingString = [prefs stringForKey:@"name_preference"];
   [prefs synchronize];
   [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com/%@", settingString]]]];
```

}

So Far So good right.  It takes the string from settings and concatenates the end of the url and all is well. when i run in the simulator i have to close the sim everytime to update the view if i change the string in settings.  Is there somewhere else i should put this code instead of "viewDidLoad"?  I want my webview to update everytime i re-open my app from settings.  Thanks for all of your help....

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in `viewDidAppear` (in the vc) or `applicationDidEnterForeground` in your app delegate.

The problem you're having is when you 'launch' the app by tapping it on the home screen, you're actually just using iOS's multitasking  to switch back to it (it never quit).

Answer (score 0):

What Alex said will work. But Apple will never accept an app with only one `UIWebView`. I hope there's more to your app if you're hoping to publish it.